# iOS-app partial GUI stuck

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I tried to open a link (first one) from [the question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4113/176217) to the possibly [deleted answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592812/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/592910#592910), it opens a [post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592812/176217), but I can't scroll it down via swipe. Looks like GUI is stuck, left panel works as expected.

If I use "go to next answer" button (right top), page twitches once, but gains the ability to scroll.

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: Same problem seen here on an iPad 2 mini, same app/iOS versions.