# Navigating from the Feed to a deleted answer on a question breaks scrolling

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. In your feed, tap an item that references a deleted post.  In this case, it tapped a comment reply on an answer I deleted.
2. Observe that the question loads, but scrolling on the view is disabled.
3. Tap the down arrow on the right side of the navigation bar.
4. Observe that the screen scrolls down to the first answer, and then scrolls back up to the question.
5. Observe scrolling is enabled again.

Expected result:

Navigating to a question from a reference to a deleted answer should not break scrolling on the question view controller.

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287150/307988) ...this is clearer though

Comment: @Cai Good find, thanks.  We'll see which one gets closed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.2.1.

A recent change caused a couple problems in the scrolling/highlighting code.

1. Because the answer was deleted, the code for getting the answer's section returned `nil`.  Due to `nil` messaging in Objective-C, this got mistranslated to the index path `Section 0, Row 0`.
2. Because we were already looking at the very top of the post, no scrolling occurred and we went on to cleanup code.  But, the cleanup code was incorrectly wrapped in a test for whether or not the cell could be highlighted. (It couldn't be because it's the question header.)

These two things got the question stuck in the waiting state where scrolling is disabled.  Now we are properly returning nil if the section is nil and calling cleanup code regardless of whether the scrolled to item can highlight.